# Combine 2 table into 1 row

Tags: sql

I have a table A with 200 rows and another table B with 300 rows. What SQL query should I use to combine them into a 500 row table?

Comment: Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

Comment: I think UNION ALL is right answer, UNION may remove duplicate in my list. and thank you

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure of your schema and if you just wanted to select the rows or add the rows to one of the tables, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: What's your main goal here, to just see the data as one table, or you want to move data from one to another?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have the same schema and you are trying to mix all the data into one table...

```
INSERT INTO a SELECT * from b
```

Comment: Will this work? never tried this before? and thank you !

Comment: This would work, unless there's an autoincrement column to prevent you to do so.  Otherwise, specifying the columns from b to a would be needed, if I remember correctly.

It still will depend if you're trying to simply view the data or move the data over.

Comment: Thank you Tiny for clarify for me !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the rows in both tables, you need to use `UNION ALL`.